# How to do group.reduce in a flat data in crossfilter

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, crossfilter, dc.js

New to crossfilter. I've a flat data which is given below:

```
 id,name,patientId,conditionId,isPrimary,age,gender,race,Status,CGI
 1,M1,1,c1,Y,33,Male,White,Discharged,0
 2,M2,1,c1,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,0
 3,M3,1,c2,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,0
 4,M4,1,c2,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,0
 5,M5,1,c3,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,0
 6,M6,1,c3,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,0
 25,M1,5,c1,Y,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
 26,M7,5,c2,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
 27,M4,5,c4,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
 28,M4,5,c1,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
 29,M4,5,c2,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
 30,M5,5,c4,N,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
 29,M2,6,c1,Y,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
 30,M2,7,c1,Y,33,Male,White,Discharged,1
```

I want to do a count on `conditionId` but since there are multiple records belonging to the same person as identified by `patientId`, the count of value `c1` should be  4 (belonging to `patientId` 1, 5, 6, 7) - because same patient may have multiple records (for eg. `patientId` of 1 is repeated 6 times and two of them has c1 which should be counted only once) . I'm struggling to write a `group.reduce` on `conditionId` but could not even start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your desired output? You simply want the count for c1 or you want a map with the counts for every conditions?

Comment: I want a count of conditionId which should be c1 : 4, c2 : 2, c3 : 1 and c4 : 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it. In the example I assumed that the first value was the `patientId` and the second value the `conditionId`. The code keeps track of grouping keys *(concatenation of the `patientId` and the `conditionId`)* that were seen already and ignores them.

```
var countMap = [
    [1, 'c1'],
    [1, 'c1'],
    [2, 'c1'],
    [2, 'c2']
].reduce(function (r, v) {
    var condition = v[1],
        groupKey = v[0] + condition;

    if (!r.seen[groupKey]) {
        r.seen[groupKey] = true; 
        r.count[condition] = (r.count[condition] || 0) + 1;
    }

    return r;

}, {seen: {}, count: {}}).count;


countMap.c1; //2
countMap.c2; //1
```

I do not know about crossfilter or dc.js, that's why I gave you a vanilla JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated to do this in Crossfilter, but the solution is similar to that provided by @plalx.

Here is a helper function I am using in one of my projects. It's not perfect, and is a bit optimized to reduce dictionary lookups, so it's not the most readable. The basic idea is you need to keep a dictionary of values seen before for each group. You only need to remember patients, because the condition is already known based on the group your are in:

```
function reduceHelper(accessorFunction) {
        var internalCount;
        return {
            add: function (p, v) {
                if(p.unique.has(accessorFunction(v))) {
                    internalCount = p.unique.get(accessorFunction(v));
                    p.unique.set(accessorFunction(v), internalCount + 1);
                } else {
                    p.unique.set(accessorFunction(v), 1);
                    ++p.count;
                }
                return p;
            },
            remove: function (p, v) {
                if(p.unique.has(accessorFunction(v))) {
                    internalCount = p.unique.get(accessorFunction(v));
                    if(internalCount == 1) {
                        p.unique.remove(accessorFunction(v));
                        --p.count;
                    } else {
                        p.unique.set(accessorFunction(v), internalCount - 1);
                    }
                }
                return p;
            },
            init: function () {
                return {unique: d3.map(), count: 0};
            }
        };
    }
```

You'll need to create a Crossfilter (xfilter) on your data and then:

```
var helperFunctions = reduceHelper(function(d) { return d.patientId; });
var dim = xfilter.dimension(function (d) { return d.conditionId; };
var group = dim.group()
              .reduce(helperFunctions.add, helperFunctions.remove, helperFunctions.init);
```

Your group will now count the number of patients that have each condition. If a condition appears more than once for a given patient, that patient will still only be counted once. At least, it will if my solution works properly :-)